# Xamarin WebSocket throws exception: ConnectFailure when for 'Release'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

When I change my Xamarin Android App from Debug to Release, the websocket starts throwing a WebsocketException: ConnectFailure (Access denied).  
However if I use it in 'debug' it works perfectly and handels the whole communication process within a few seconds. 
Any idea why this might be happening? There are no #IF DEBUG statements in my code, also the app already worked fine a few weeks ago on Release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, sometimes problems get more obvious once you type them out. 
 I had to add 'INTERNET' as a required permission to my app. No idea why it worked before, but that did the trick.

Comment: when running in DEBUG mode the INTERNET permission is implicitly granted